# DeployR Open - Restrict file system access

Tags: r, revolution-r, deployr

According to the [DeployR documentation](https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/admin/security/#processcontrols) each session is locked down:

"By default, R sessions executing on the DeployR grid are not authorized to access files or directories outside of the R working directory"

However, I have been able to upload a simple script using a user that has Basic_User role and that reads a file from the c:\ drive on windows.

```
t <- read.table("C:\\MyFile.csv")
t
```

How do you lock down access to the file system? I seem to have missed something.

Comment: Immediately above the statement that you quoted, it says that "This form of security is available for DeployR Enterprise on Linux platforms only."

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that.